# How to set all texts at the same y coordinate on a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

```
library(ggplot2)
Center<-paste("Center", 1:10, sep=" ")

Values<-c(102, 125, 400, 210, 323, 178, 205, 189,327, 240)
mydata<-data.frame(Center,Values)

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=Center, y=Values,fill=Center,label=Values))+
  geom_col()+coord_flip()+
  geom_text(position = position_stack())
```

What I want is not to put the texts at the top of each barplot, but align them all to `Values` axis= 150, in a word, superimpose them

Comment: `geom_text(y = 150)`

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Thomas